# Adding Tap GestureRecognizer to MKOverlay

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, tap, mkoverlay

I am trying to get overlays on my map to responds to touches. Hence, I wanted to add a UIGestureRecognizer for taps to the MKOverlayView that is created in the method mapView:viewForOverlay.

I added the following code in this method:

```
if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]])
{

    MKPolygonView*    aView = [[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithPolygon:(MKPolygon*)overlay];

    UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];

    tap.delegate = self;
    aView.fillColor = color;
    aView.strokeColor = color;
    aView.lineWidth = 2;
    [aView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    return aView;
}
```

In addition, I conform to the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate - Protocol and I implemented the method handleGesture:. So far this method is never called.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You are not assigning the number of tap property for UITapGestureRecognizer.